# PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Given a string like the following

```
$text= 'You must call  [[abc\base\Object::
        canGetProperty()|canGetProperty()]] or
        [[abc\base\Object::canSetProperty()|
        canSetProperty()]] respectively.'
```

I would like to change it into

```
'You must call [canGetProperty()](www.domain.com/
 abc-base-object.html#canGetProperty()) or 
 [canSetProperty()]((www.domain.com/abc-
 base-object.html#canGetProperty()) respectively.'
```

I have tried:

```
  $text = 'You must call  [[abc\base\Object::
          canGetProperty()|canGetProperty()]] or 
          [[abc\base\Object::canSetProperty()|
          canSetProperty()]] respectivement.';

  $pattern = '/\[\[(([^\:]+\\\)+[^\:]+)\:\:([^\|]+)\|([^\]]+)\]\]/';
  $replacement = '[$3](www.domain.com/$1.html#$3)';
  echo $text.'<br/>'; //original text
  echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

And I get

```
You must call [canGetProperty()](www.domain.com/abc
\base\Object.html#canGetProperty()) or [canSetProperty()]
(www.domain.com/abc\base\Object.html#canSetProperty()) 
respectivement.
```

this is not far from what I want except for the fact that `abc\base\Object` is not turned into `abc-base-object`

---

How can I have `\` replaced by `-` not knowing the number of time it appears and how to turn initial uppercase into lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using [***preg_replace_callback***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), `str_replace` and `strtolower` functions:

```
$text = 'You must call  [[abc\base\Object::canGetProperty()|canGetProperty()]] or [[abc\base\Object::canSetProperty()|canSetProperty()]] respectively.';

$pattern = '/\[\[(\w+\\\\\w+\\\\\w+)::(\w+\(\))\|\2\]\]/i';
$new_text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){    
    return "[{$matches[2]}]" 
            . "(www.domain.com/" . str_replace("\\", "-", strtolower($matches[1]))
            . ".html#{$matches[2]})";
}, $text);

print_r($new_text);
```

The output:

```
You must call  [canGetProperty()](www.domain.com/abc-base-object.html#canGetProperty()) or [canSetProperty()](www.domain.com/abc-base-object.html#canSetProperty()) respectively.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect.